# i want to open a multilayer TIFF in Photoshop, or convert Tiff file to PSD file using python only

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tiff, psd

Basically i have created a tiff multilayered file in python using pillow library it is having 8 layers basically tiff is created successfully it is even getting open in normal windows image viewer and i can see all the layers but when i open that tiff file in photoshop it shows only first layer other layers are not visible in photoshop then i use online tool photopea to open that tiff file so there were all the layers and it was like what i am looking for but my requirement is to open file in photoshop with layers so i just convert that file to psd file using the same tool and it get opens in photoshop as layered.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Load the image using OpenCV
image = cv2.imread("Testing_samples/test5.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Convert BGR to RGB
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Reshape the array for clustering
x = image_rgb.reshape(-1, 3)

# Apply KMeans clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4).fit(x)
segmented_image = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_]
segmented_image = segmented_image.reshape(image_rgb.shape)

num_clusters = 4

# Create a directory to save the TIFF file
tiff_dir = "Testing_Tiff"
os.makedirs(tiff_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Create an empty list to store segmented layer images
layer_images = []

# Plot each segmented color cluster
for i in range(1, num_clusters + 1):
    boolean_index = kmeans.labels_ == (i - 1)

    if boolean_index.sum() > 0:
        segmented_layer = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.uint8)

        mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=bool)
        mask.flat[boolean_index] = True

        for channel in range(image.shape[-1]):
            segmented_layer[:, :, channel][mask] = kmeans.cluster_centers_[i - 1][channel]

        # Add transparency channel
        alpha_channel = np.zeros_like(image[:, :, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
        alpha_channel[mask] = 255  # Set pixels in the segment to fully opaque
        segmented_layer = np.dstack([segmented_layer, alpha_channel])

        # Convert the segmented layer to a PIL Image
        pil_layer = Image.fromarray(segmented_layer, 'RGBA')

        # Append the segmented layer image to the list
        layer_images.append(pil_layer)

# Save the list of layer images as a single TIFF file with layers
layered_tiff_path = os.path.join(tiff_dir, "test_4_16_layers.tiff")
layer_images[0].save(layered_tiff_path, save_all=True, append_images=layer_images[1:], format="TIFF")

print(f"Segmented layers TIFF file saved: {layered_tiff_path}")
```

so from the code you can see i have created one Tiff file using python code now i want to convert this file into PSD file using python because when i open this Tiff layered file in photoshop then only the top layer is getting open rest of them are not showing but in normal windows viewer i can see the layers so i hope now you got my point

Thank you.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] showing ***how*** you created your multi-layer TIFF - even if the first layer is just red, the second layer just green and the third is just solid blue and so on...

Comment: opencv doesn't do this. it's for computer vision, not for converting commercial file formats. -- help in using photoshop is certainly offtopic for this site. perhaps https://superuser.com/ is the right place? there might be something even better-fitting

Comment: Proper sentences and paragraphs please. The only thing I can see in this wall of text is `photoshop`, `multipage tiff` and `convert to psd`. I suspect graphicsdesign.stackexchange.com is more appropriate than SO. For example, in [How to handle multiple page design projects in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/how-to-handle-multiple-page-design-projects-in-photoshop) people say that's impossible, no matter the file format. The solution is to export each page to a separate file.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Pages aren't layers in the first place. It makes no more sense to treat a multi-page TIFF as layers than treating a PDF as layers. If you want *layers* you shouldn't create a multi-page TIFF in the first place

Comment: @MarkSetchell as you said i have updated my question with code as well